# Updating/Pulling a value in an Array contained in a Subdocument Array in Mongodb/Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a document in a mongoDB collection which looks like this:

```
 _id:'5d4721e0b904e825755eaf89',
 sellers:[
   {_id:'5d5eeaf7867a4e1e9a1219e6'
    bizs:[
       {_id:'6a5eeaf7867a4e124a1219a4',
       name:'Shop A'}
    ]},

 ]
```

I need to pull/delete Shop A (by using its _id for instance)

So far I have tried using Positional Operator $ but I still couldn't access it.

Below is my code of what I have tried:

```
Model.findByIdAndUpdate(someId, {
  "$pull": {
      'sellers.bizs.$._id':itemId
  }
})
```

But I get the *'The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query'* error Message.

Now, I would like to pull that Shop A out of that bizs Array of which is in the Sellers array.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want entire object to be pulled out or just name in that object ?

Comment: @srinivasy I need the entire document to be pulled out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this :

```
Model.findByIdAndUpdate(someId,
{ $pull : { 'sellers.$[].bizs': {"_id" : itemId,"name" : "Shop A" } }})
```

Here `"name" : "Shop A"` is optional.

Comment: Works like a charm... You saved a million lives!! Thanks @srinivas